# How could I use the html a tag to change div width and height?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

```
<div class="panel">
    <a href onclick="manipulate()">Show Quick Admin (↑)</a>
    <div class="hidden">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="admin.php">Panel</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

so i am tying to make a "quick admin bar", for the site i'm making. this is the code i am using, don't mind the fact it's bad. i tried to make it check the height and width of the div "panel", and if it was 20px, change the "a" tag's innerHTML, show the "hidden" div, and make it so that if you click the "a" tag again it will set the div height back from 300px to 20px, change the a tag's innerHTML again, and hide the "hidden" div from viewing. how would i do this?

javascript:

```
function manipulate() {
    if ($("#panel").height() == "20") {
        document.getElementsByClassName("panel").style.height= "300px";
        document.getElementsByClassName("hidden").style = "";
    }
}
```

css:

```
.panel {
    padding:10px;
    background:#fffdbb;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:15px;
    width:225px; 
    height:20px; /* 300px */
    right:15px;
    border:10;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:2px;
    border-color:red;
}

.hidden {
    text-indent: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

right now it just doesn't do anything when Show Quick Admin is clicked. how can i fix this?

Comment: This `$("#panel")` is JQuery and it addresses the element with id=panel, which does not exist. Did you include the JQuery js file? Try to use `$("div.panel")` instead

Comment: Also, use `.` instead of `#` for class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use [0]

```
 document.getElementsByClassName("panel")[0].style.height= "300px"
```

Why dont you use this if you are using jquery?

```
$(".panel").css("height","300px");
```

I would suggest you to use id instead of class

```
<div class="panel">
```

vs

```
<div id="panel">
```

## The proper way of Using

http://jsfiddle.net/sb3fY/1/

```
    <div id="panel">
    <span class="link1">Show Quick Admin (↑)</span>
    <div class="hidden">
        <ul>
            <li>
               <a href="admin.php">Panel</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$(".link1").on("click",function(){
  $("#panel").toggleClass("open");
  $("#hidden").toggle();
});
```

CSS

```
    #panel {
    padding:10px;
    background:#fffdbb;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:15px;
    width:225px; 
    height:20px; /* 300px */
    right:15px;
    border:10;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:2px;
    border-color:red;
}

.hidden {
    text-indent: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#panel.open {
 height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: thanks. how do you think i could "hide and unhide" the div "hidden"?

Comment: oh haha, it didn't work in firefox but it did in chrome. odd! thank you for your help :) it's not allowing me to vote up because i need 15 rep.